# How to read multiple lines of a batch file using "("

Tags: batch-file

So, long time ago I was really into batch files. I'm coming back to that, but for the life of me I can't find my preferred way of getting lines of text from a file.

It went something like this:

```
(
set /p %var1%=
set /p %var2%=
)>textfile.txt
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this question should've been marked as a duplicate because OP isn't asking "How do I read a data file"?  He's asking "How do I read a data file *via redirection*?" which is a significant distinction.

Comment: OP, you can loop `set /P` to read lines via redirection. Example: `<textfile.txt ( for /L %%I in (0,1,5) do set /P "line5=" )` After that, `%line5%` will contain the fifth line of the data file. This is more efficient than a `for /f` loop, and I think it's what you're looking for. If you want to read *all* lines and set as an array, use `for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('find /c /v "" "%textfile%"') do set /a linecount = %%I`.  Then you can use `<"%textfile%" ( for /L %%I in (0,1,%linecount%) do set /P "line[%%I]=" )` to populate your array.  Wish I could've posted this as an answer. `-_-`

Comment: it's `set /p var=` (without the percent signs) and you want to read FROM the textfile, not write TO it, so it's `<`, not `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops! :-)

You are trying to read from a file, not write to it. So you need `<`, not `>`.

Also, you only use percents when you are expanding the variable, not when you are defining it.

Lastly, you should explicitly undefine any prior value before reading, because reading an empty line will preserve any existing variable value.

```
(
  set "var1="
  set /p "var1="
  set "var2="
  set /p "var2="
) <textfile.txt
```

As rojo stated in his comment, you may be better off using an array concept if you are reading an arbitrary number of lines. However, you must first determine the total number of lines to read.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Determine number of lines
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" <textfile.txt') do set "cnt=%%N"

:: Read the file into an array
<textfile.txt (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do (
    set "str.%%N="
    set /p "str.%%N="
  )
)

:: Display the array values
for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do echo(!str.%%N!)
```

Using SET /P is the fastest way to read a file into variables, and it avoids issues with FOR /F regarding empty lines and `!` being corrupted if delayed expansion is enabled. But SET /P has its own limitations:

- Lines in the source file must be terminated by \r\n (carriage return and linefeed)
- Every line must be <= 1021 bytes long
- Trailing control characters are stripped from the line

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted.