# Looping through text file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have information in a text file that I need to extract and put into a loop. For simplicity, lets assume the first line is a person and the second line is their favorite color.

Text file looks like this:

> ```
> tim
> red
> sarah
> blue and yellow
> sam
> green
> ```

I'd like an echo output to look like this:

```
tim likes red
sarah likes blue and yellow
sam likes green
```

What I have for code so far is below:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%Name %%color in (C:\textfile.txt) do echo %%Name likes %%color
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I certainly didn't make that clear... I want to have a loop that can associate the person with their favorite color.  What I have now is not working.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and type `for /?` -- you will find that your syntax is not correct...

Comment: So [edit] your post and make it clear, instead of burying that extremely relevant information in the clutter of comments.

Comment: I changed the question around, my apologies.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. Anyway meanwhile bear in mind that you can only declare one variable in the `for` and it can only be one character long (`%n in (C:\...`).

Comment: I tried something of what's here but I couldn't do what you need. Maybe you have more luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560855/how-to-read-multiple-lines-of-a-batch-file-using

Comment: Any luck with this? Could you solve it?

Comment: @chew224, you never replied or marked this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  set /a "x=(x+1) %% 2"
  if !x! == 1 set name=%%a
  if !x! == 0 echo !name! likes %%a. 
)
```

Comment: Works exactly as intended.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your task I see the following options:

1. using a `for /F` loop and setting and clearing a variable (`NAME`) alternatingly during every other iteration to await the colour associated with a certain name:

   ```dos
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "NAME="
   for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%L in ("textfile.txt") do (
       if defined NAME (
           echo !NAME! likes %%L
           set "NAME="
       ) else (
           set "NAME=%%L"
       )
   )
   endlocal
   ```
2. determining half of the number of lines in advance, using a `for /L` loop and reading two lines at once per iteration by using input redirection (`<`):

   ```dos
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for /F %%C in ('^< "textfile.txt" find /C /V ""') do set /A "HALF=%%C/2"

   < "textfile.txt" (
       for /L %%I in (1,1,%HALF%) do (
           set /P NAME=
           set /P COLOUR=
           echo !NAME! likes !COLOUR!
       )
   )
   endlocal
   ```